# Powerapps date and time SharePoint timezone issue

Tags: sharepoint, timezone, powerapps

I have a SharePoint list with a customised PowerApps form. There is a date and time field and I would like to capture the exact date and time that the user enters in the field, independent of the time zone the user is based in. My SharePoint site regional settings is UTC but when users from EST enter 9:00 on the PowerApps form, it is saved as 5:00 on SharePoint. I do not want these conversions to take place. Can someone please assist me with this.
Thank you.
SK

Answer (score 0):

Check out the Converting to UTC section here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-platform/power-fx/reference/function-dateadd-datediff

using the TimeZoneOffset() to convert all the times to UTC no matter the user's location.